# EMI about Y capacitor and common mode noise

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc, emi-filtering

I do not get how the capacitor localized between the input voltage and the earth can help to reduce the common mode noise as the input voltage is at a voltage which is fixed and the earth voltage is also fixed. So there is no variation across the capacitor and no current can flow through it. Can someone can explain how it works?

I completely understand that a current flow through the parasitic capacitor between the drain and the earth as the voltage drain is changing and the voltage earth is fixed.

[image]
Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: Jess, the picture does not appear to show a situation where common mode noise is relevant. More context is needed and a diagram where terminals are marked so that anyone answering will understand what they connect to.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Tell me if my edit helps

Comment: The input voltage may not be as fixed as you think it is : especially if it is fixed at the other end of a cable (which has inductance and thus high impedance at high frequencies)